# Memory management issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Currently, I am facing the most severe problem of all time while creating iphone applications which is memory management issue.
I am reading the XML file and storing in the database using SQLITE. While reading the XML file, I create an object of the class file TestFile and allocate the space to it. So when it reads a start tag it allocates the space and when it finds the end tag, it will release the space and deallocate for next tags.
//class TestFile

```
@interface TestFile : NSObject {

NSString *id;
NSString *number;
NSNumber *size_A;
NSNumber *size_B;
NSNumber *places;
NSString *spaces;
NSString *name;
NSString *print;
NSString *description;
NSNumber *formats;
NSString *purchases;
NSNumber *active;
UIImage *appLogo;
NSUInteger starred;
}
```

But for some reason, when I check the Instruments to know the memory allocation, the memory space allocated to testFile = [[TestFile alloc] init]  is around 32 KB which is killing the application to load on iphone 3GS. Am I doing some thing wrong here or can I do it in some other way ?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if([elementName isEqual:@"root"]) {
    self.exhArray = [NSMutableArray array] ;
}

else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"object"])
{
    testFile = [[TestFile alloc] init] ;
}
}

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

if(!currentElementValue) 
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"])
    return;

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"object"]) {
    [self.exhArray addObject:testFile];
    [testFile release];
    testFile = nil;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"key_id"])
    [testFile setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
 [currentElementValue release];
currentElementValue = nil;
```

}

Comment: You belive this to be "the most severe problem of all time" - You don't think you're being *just a little bit* melodramatic there? :-) On a serious note, I presume you mean 32MB rather than 32KB?

Comment: What does the `TestFile` class declaration look like, and what does its `init` method do?  If that class is allocating a huge amount of memory, then this has nothing to do with your XML parsing.

Comment: @middaparka: I am not trying to be so dramatic but just the issue of handling memory management is not easy to handle. And no, the allocated space is 32 KB and the overall space allocated for my application is 210 KB. Just wanted to knw if I can do it in another way or if I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @kristopher : I have edited my code to show my TestFile class declaration.

Comment: How is it killing your iPhone 3GS? Is it crashing? Are you receiving memory warnings?

Comment: It is receiving "Received memory level warning Level = 1" and also goes to level = 2. and finally when it reaches level = 2, it crashes.

Comment: 210 KB is not much memory, how much XML are you parsing? # of objects?

Comment: there are 550 number of objects with each one of them having 10 fields.

Comment: Alright now the next question, what size is the xml file? So instruments is saying each TestFile alloc/init is using 32k of mem, So you have 32k * 550 = ~17.2MB in memory on top of the amount of xml being loaded into memory. You might have to persist/flush some of your TestFiles to disk until you are done parsing and/or only keep the ones in memory that you need.

Comment: The total size of the XML Document is around 143 KB. But I am parsing the XML file through URL and I am storing the data locally using NSData.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark - the XML parsing may be ok - though I did not check too specifically on your code.

I would suggest you to check  on the `UIImage` instance `appLogo`. Once instantiated, that baby will contain a decoded image (commonly 4 byte per pixel). Often enough, you may come across images that seem small enough when looking at their file-size. You should however look at their total resolution to get the effective memory needed for keeping that data in memory.

Another suggestion would be to add some logging into your parsing code to see if the expected is actually happening.